# Twitter API : How to add people I follow to a list? (Received Error: Code 34, 404, page doesn't exist)

Tags: node.js, rest, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am trying to add all the people I follow to a new Twitter list(named personal, I created) but I am getting error 404 with my code (I created a developer Twitter account and passed the credentials, which is working fine):

Here is the script (resetting on 80, as I read I can't add directly more than 80 people, though here I am just passing two Twitter handles only):

[Also, is this going as a get request, does it need to go as a post, if so, how do I send a post request in this]

```
//Include the node module
var Twitter = require( 'twitter-node-client' ).Twitter;

//Get this data from your twitter apps dashboard
var config = { 
//demo values
    "consumerKey": "zKuw", 
    "consumerSecret": "isdfsd", 
    "accessToken": "852", 
    "accessTokenSecret": "81c",
    "callBackUrl": "http://localhost:3000/" // Do I need to change it?
};

//Init the Twitter API client with the API key

var twitter = new Twitter( config );

//Callback functions
var error = function ( err, response, body ) {
    console.log( err );
};
var success = function ( data ) {
    console.log( data );
};

// List to add, adding two handles initially 

var myList = "bchesky, sama";
console.log( myList );

var myStrings = myList.split( "," );
console.log( myStrings );

let i = 0;
let j = 0;
var myText = "";

while ( ( i + j ) < myStrings.length ) {
    myText += myStrings[ i + j ];
    i++;

    if ( i == 80 || i + j >= myStrings.length ) {
        j = j + i;
        i = 0;
        //Add members 
        twitter.listAddMembers( {
            owner_screen_name: "abhishek_123",
            slug: "personal",
            list_id: 133851,
            screen_name: myText
        }, error, success );

        console.log( myText );
        myText = "";
    }
    else {
        myText += ", ";
    }

}
```

And the error/output I am getting is :

```
Abhisheks-MacBook-Air:upload-twitter-list-master abhishek$ node server.js
bchesky, sama
[ 'bchesky', ' sama' ]
bchesky,  sama
URL [https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/members/create_all.json]
{
  statusCode: 404,
  data: '{"errors":[{"code":34,"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist."}]}'
}
```

Thanks in advance, every help is highly appreciated.